# What are the technial and programming requirements for writing a stealth keylogger?

Tags: malware, antivirus, keyloggers

I'm planning to write/code one such stealth keylogger that would bypass detection by a certain antivirus. (I don't want to name the vendor as I know how good Google queries are against StackExchange websites).

I don't want to just download any keylogger from internet and try to encode it to evade detection. Writing code myself I would have the ability to make changes as I go; obscuration on both high-level and low-level language. I like control too.

It seems naive but is it true that keyloggers are a thing of the past, probably because of how effective AV's have become in detecting such programs?

I want some nice points on how can one easily write a robust, effective key logger preferably for a Windows environment?

Comment: Presumably you'll be writing the keylogger in Visual Basic, right?

Comment: This is really a programming question, not a security one. Closed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an open source keylogger such as [pykeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page). It is written in python and should be fairly easy to understand. The zipped download is only about 154 KB.

Sorry, I have no idea how to evade detection.